# Calculate Percentage in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, count, percentage

I am trying to produce a MySQL table that contains a column displaying the percentage corresponding to one count over another with the same grouping. Overall, I want to combine the following two queries into one that, instead of displaying a count, displays a percentage. Here are the two queries:

```
SELECT machine, COUNT(machine)
FROM rtcdb.session
WHERE project = "CSC032"
  AND (qc_gsr = 'green'
    AND qc_hr = 'green'
    AND qc_acz = 'green'
    AND qc_bre = 'green'
  )
GROUP BY machine;
```

&

```
SELECT machine, COUNT(machine)
FROM rtcdb.session
WHERE project = "CSC032"
GROUP BY machine;
```

There are scenarios where the first query will produce less rows than the second - this happens when there are machines that do not have any successes (greens) at all. How would I combine these queries into one that computes the percentage of all machines that are successes (essentially, a success rate), and displays this in its own column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that

```
SELECT
  machine
, COUNT(DISTINCT machine) AS "nb"
, COUNT(DISTINCT
    IF(qc_gsr = "green"
   AND qc_hr = "green"
   AND qc_acz = "green"
   AND qc_bre = "green"
    ), machine, NULL)
  ) AS "green_nb"
, COUNT(DISTINCT
    IF(qc_gsr = "green"
   AND qc_hr = "green"
   AND qc_acz = "green"
   AND qc_bre = "green"
    ), machine, NULL)
  ) / COUNT(machine) * 100 AS "%"
FROM rtcdb.session
WHERE project = "CSC032"
GROUP BY machine
;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, really appreciate it. The query you wrote is putting me in the right direction, but is unfortunately computing inaccurate values (the reason of which I am unsure). It seems your query is producing a much higher percentage than what it actually should be. For example, instead of coming up with 2 for the count of  green_nb for one of the machines, it is coming up with 11, which is the total count of that machine. It seems that the green_nb count is coming up with a number that is consistently equal to or slightly less than the total count. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you should use `DISTINCT`. But what I don't understand is if you count `machine` and group by `machine` it should always return 1. Could you provide a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) ?

Comment: I figured it out! This is what I have now:

Comment: SELECT
  machine
, COUNT(
    IF("green" IN (qc_gsr) AND "green" in (qc_hr) AND "green" in (qc_acz) AND "green" in (qc_bre), machine, NULL)
  ) AS "green_nb"
, COUNT(machine) AS "nb"
, COUNT(
    IF("green" IN (qc_gsr) AND "green" in (qc_hr) AND "green" in (qc_acz) AND "green" in (qc_bre), machine, NULL)
  ) / COUNT(machine) * 100 AS "%"
FROM rtcdb.session
WHERE project = "CSC032"
GROUP BY machine;

Comment: Ok, actually you can use `=` instead of `IN`. See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Just so that you are aware of the technique, another approach would be to use your existing queries as subqueries in something like the following (not tested):

```
select machine, total.count, green.count, green.count*100/total.count as percentage
  from (<subquery1>) green, (<subquery2>) total right join by green.machine=total.machine`
```

You would need to alias `count(machine)` to `count` in the subqueries.